# Ошибка в коде сортировки, пытаясь найти минимальное число слагаемых

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x

Решаю задачу:

По данным числам 1 <= n <= 30 и 1 <= w <= 10<sup>9</sup> и набору чисел 1<=v<sub>1</sub>, ... v<sub>n</sub><=10<sup>9</sup> найдите минимальное число `k`, для которого число `w` можно представить как сумму `k` чисел из набора {v<sub>1</sub> ... v<sub>n</sub>}. Каждое число из набора можно использовать сколь угодно раз. Известно, что в наборе есть единица и что для любой пары чисел из набора одно из них делится на другое. Гарантируется, что в оптимальном ответе число слагаемых не превосходит 10<sup>4</sup>.

Выведите число k и сами слагаемые.

Пример тестовых данных:

```
4 90 1 2 10 50
```

Ответ:

```
5 50 10 10 10 10
```

Мой вариант:

```
def solve_sum(num_array, value):
    dividers = [i for i in num_array if i <= value]
    dividers = sorted(dividers, reverse=True)
    res = []
    n = 0
    while value:
        res += [dividers[n]] * (value // dividers[n])
        k = (value // dividers[n])
        value %= dividers[n]
        n += 1
    return str(n)+' '+" ".join(map(str, res))


results = input().split(' ')
results = [int(i) for i in results]
value = results[1]
num_array = results[2:]

print(solve_sum(num_array, value))
```

Однако, что-то неверно и выдает ошибку:

```
Failed test #1. Wrong answer
Input:
4 90 1 2 10 50
Your output:
2 50 10 10 10 10
Correct output:
5 50 10 10 10 10
```

Что не так?

Comment: Наверно должно быть `n += k`

Answer (score 1):

У Вас в цикле

```
while value:
    res += [dividers[n]] * (value // dividers[n])
    k = (value // dividers[n])
    value %= dividers[n]
    n += 1
```

Во-второй итерации значение `value` становится равным нулю, и цикл завершается. Строка `n += 1` подсчитывает количество циклов, соответственно она равна 2. А Вам нужно сосчитать количество делителей, поэтому её нужно поменять на `n += k`.

Answer (score 1):

`n` у вас индекс, а не количество слагаемых. Минимально, добавьте `k=0` перед циклом и `k += (value // dividers[n])` и соответственно `str(k)` в конце вместо `str(n)`.

Можно рассматривать нахождение слагаемых для суммы как запись введённого числа `w` в системе исчисления с переменными основаниями `v`, тогда число слагаемых это просто сумма коэффициентов перед соответствующими основаниями (сколько раз основание повторяется в числе):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def convert(number, bases):
    for base in sorted(bases, reverse=True): # O(n log n)
        digit, number = divmod(number, base) # O(log w)
        for _ in range(digit):
            yield base

n, w, *v = map(int, input().split())
assert len(v) == n
terms = list(convert(w, v))
print(len(terms), *terms)
```